# ODE with global inequality constraint on derivative

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, game-theory

The problem is solving the ODE $f''(x)+a_1f'(x)+a_2f(x)=g(x)$ with boundary conditions $f(c)=h(c)$, $f(d)=h(d)$, where $c,d$ must be such that $f'(x)\geq b\;\forall x\in[c,d]\subseteq\mathbb{R}$. The constants $a_1,a_2,b\in\mathbb{R}$ are known. The functions $g(x),h(x)$ are smooth and known. The parameters $c,d$ and the function $f(x)$ are not known and should be solved for. It is unlikely that $c,d$ can be solved for uniquely, so the solution would involve a region $D\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ for which if $(c,d)\in D$, the ODE can be solved.

What is this type of problem called? What keywords should I search for to find a solution method?

It somewhat resembles differential-algebraic equations, mathematical programming with equilibrium constraints, bilevel optimization.

This arises in a continuous-time game in which I'm trying to find an equilibrium.

Answer (score 0):

This is a linear second order non-homogeneous ODE, if you know g(x) you can try find its general solution and then use the contraints at hand to determine the constants of integration and the parameters c,d.

Comment: This does not really work due to the nonstandard constraint $f'(x)\geq b\;\forall x\in[c,d]$. The boundary conditions are given implicitly by this constraint, so using the boundaries to determine constants is somewhat difficult.

Comment: Yes, but this depends on the analytic solution $f(x,c_1,c_2)$ if it's a polynomial with respect to $x$ or expressed with exponentials the boundary for x, $c<x<d$, might help you bound $f^\prime(x)$. Also you can use a Computer Algebra System (CAS) like Mathematica or Maple to try find a pair of values (c,d) that satisfy your constraints. But bear in mind that you have 4 unknowns $(c_1,c_2,c,d)$ and 2 equations and one inequality so the boundary problem most likely will not have a unique solution or might not have a solution at all.

Comment: You are right that $c,d$ are not unique. A region of $(c,d)$ values for which the ODE can be solved is a component of the full solution. I'm using Mathematica to solve the problem numerically. I would like to know whether such problems have been studied, since even a partial characterization would help me.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't help you with the characterization. Numerically speaking, you need to do a two-dimensional Newton-Raphson on the pair $(c,d)$ where in each step you use the shooting method to calculate $f^\prime(x)$. When you find an region that satisfy your conditions then by looking at the second derivative at the boundary of the domain you can see if you can enlarge it to have the maximal contiguous domain. For those reasons, it's better to turn your ODE to a system of order one ODEs.